# Alternative to LuaJit?

Tags: lua, jit

Are there any still active projects that could serve as an alternative to LuaJIT and that work with the latest version of lua(5.3.5)?

I saw a few projects such as MoonJIT and raptorjit but they seem to not support the latest version or be too complicated.

Comment: There is [Ravi](https://github.com/dibyendumajumdar/ravi).  But AFAIK the compilation is not automatic - you should manually invoke `ravi.compile()` for those functions you want to be compiled.